# POST array of checkbox values

Tags: php, arrays, post, checkbox

I'm making a website for my uni course so it's somewhat basic in a few places, but my current aim is to create an array of values based on checkboxes. This will become a basic basket/shopping cart so that the user can list the item's they want to take to the checkout.

I'm having trouble posting the values from my checkboxes though. I can only post one at a time, but what I intend to do is select multiple images at once and then add them in one go.

This is spread out over a few pages now and it's quite dynamic. Here are the relevant sections of code that I'm working with:

**PhotographerAccount**
(displays the gallery based on the photographer you are viewing)

```
<div class="container">
<!--Form to select items to put in "basket"-->
<form action="basket.php" method="POST">
<!--Gallery-->
<div style="margin-bottom:50; margin-top:50; height:600px; border:3px solid #adadad; border-radius: 10px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; background-color: #e0e0e0">
   <?php include "personalGallery.php" ?>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-info btn-lg">Add selected to basket (<small id="y">0</small>)</button>
</form>
</div>
```

**personalGallery**
(creates the gallery and the checkboxes)

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $photoID = $row['uploadID'];
    $photoNm = $row['photoName'];

    //Photo styling
    echo "<div class='col-sm-3 text-center' style='background-color:#e5e5e5; margin-bottom: 20px; border-width: 0 2 0 2; border-style: solid; border-color: #e0e0e0'>";

    //Checkbox for form and Photo name as a label
    echo "<div class='checkbox'>";
    echo "<label><input onclick='updateCount()' class='z' type='checkbox' name='selection[]' value='".$photoID."'><strong>".$photoNm."</strong></label>";
    echo "</div>";

    //Photo
    echo "<img src='photographersarea/PhotoUploads/".$photoID."' alt='".$photoNm."' style='height:200px;max-width: 100%'>";

    //Close Styling
    echo "</div>";

  }
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
```

From here the form should be posting the data to basket.php, but when I test the array using print_r($_POST['selection'] or even print_r($_POST) I only see value. From the things I've read this should have made an array that I can work with.

Any ideas how I can post the data as an array?

Thanks!
(Will update post and make note of updates if needed)

**UPDATES**
 - Fixed typo

Comment: You access the array values via $_POST['selection'] you have written 'selected'.

Comment: Ah yeah, typo! It should have been print_r($_POST['selection'])

Answer (score 0):

use var_dump you will see keys as well or you can get key from array_keys()

Comment: Tried that and I'm still only getting one value back unfortunately

Comment: This is my output from 4 checkboxes and using var_dump to display the results, string(21) "223859655aad5e5a5201c". As each image has a unique reference there should be 4 separate values, right?

Comment: Ok for some reason I'm now getting multiple values come through in the form of an array... Wondering if this could be due to my server

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to have wasted your time, turns out the code was fine, but the host was having some kind of problem!

Code above works fine now. Lets hope this doesn't happen again when I come to hand in the assignment!